# sympyのPiecewiseから式を取りだす方法を教えて下さい

Tags: python, sympy

(参考) 積分 - 読書ノート v1.4.0dev - プレハブ小屋
https://showa-yojyo.github.io/notebook/python-sympy/integrals.html

```
from sympy import *
var('s,t,x')
myLT1=laplace_transform(exp(-t), t, s)
print(myLT1)
myLT2=inverse_laplace_transform(myLT1[0], s, t)
print(myLT2)
#-------------------------------------------------------
myLT3=integrate(exp(-s*t), (t, 0, 1))
print(myLT3)
print(myLT3[1])
#-------------------------------------------------------
#(1/(s + 1), 0, True)
#exp(-t)*Heaviside(t)
#Piecewise((1, Eq(s, 0)), (1/s - exp(-s)/s, True))
#TypeError: 'Piecewise' object does not support indexing
```

1/s - exp(-s)/sを取りだす方法を教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

---

20180501 追記
full script :

```
from sympy import *
var('s,t')
myLT3=integrate(exp(-s*t), (t, 0, 1))
print(myLT3)
u = symbols('u', positive=True)
print(myLT3.subs(s, u).subs(u, s))
#Piecewise((1, Eq(s, 0)), (1/s - exp(-s)/s, True))
#1/s - exp(-s)/s
```

(参考) Piecewise - Wolfram Language Documentation
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問の意味が「`Piecewise` オブジェクトの構成要素シーケンスにアクセスする方法を知りたい」ならば `Piecewise.args` メンバーを参照するのがよいでしょう。このメンバーは `tuple` オブジェクトであり、構成要素は式と条件のペアです。次のようにして「取り出す」ことができるでしょう：

```
print(myLT3.args[1][0])
```

ただし、添字の決め方は別途ご検討ください。いつでも `.args[1][0]` にお目当ての式があることは保証されないようです（後述）。

質問の意味が「この積分で値が 1 とならない場合の式を表示なり評価したい」ならば、`Piecewise.subs` メソッドで適切な変数を代入して、所望の式表現を得るという方法もあります。例えば次のようにします：

```
u = symbols('u', positive=True)
print(myTL3.subs(s, u))
```

ご参考までに、私の環境で解決策候補のコードを実行した画像をお見せします。おそらく使用した SymPy のバージョンが違うためでしょうが、`Piecewise` オブジェクトの構成がそちらの結果と異なっています（したがって添字の決め打ちは危険ということです）。

[image: How to access components of a Piecewise]

以上です。